# UDP packets lost (LAN-Netcat) , switching server-client sides packets are OK

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, port

I was trying to run a game that uses UDP socket on LAN , but could not see the other computer in my network, so i tried somethings to see what can give rise to this issue. The running OS's are:

```
PC1: Linux Ubuntu
PC2: Windows 10
```

The issue is that when PC2 is listening , the PC1 can send and receive packets:

```
$PC2> ncat -ul 8888
$PC1> ncat -u PC2 8888
OK
```

Send and receive works OK, However when client/server is switched, the packets are lost.

```
$PC1> ncat -ul 8888
$PC2> ncat -u PC1 8888
```

On a side note, on PC2 when trying to send the packet with Pythons `socket.sendto` function the return value is not `-1` and is the size of the packet.
Also turning of firewall on PC2 doesn't help.

This is weird problem since one-way works fine but switching the client/server the packets are loss.

Comment: You say the loss is occurring when PC1 is listening, but is the firewall disabled on PC1? By default, firewalls will prevent inbound, not outbound, traffic. Also, since UDP is fire-and-forget protocol, you can't get a socket error message if the UDP segment is successfully sent but not received since the socket has no idea whether or not it was received; that would be a TCP thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the hosts (*PC1*) might be behind a [*NAT*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), while the other (*PC2*) is in a public network. It should be clear if it is the case, if you provide ip addresses of the hosts. Presence of *NAT* would explain why switching client and server breaks.

When a packet is sent from *PC1* to *PC2*, *NAT* would add an ip translation record of the form
**(PC1 internal ip address, port1) -- (PC1 public ip address, port2)**, 
and translate  internal address to public and vice versa whenever needed.

When *PC1* becomes a server, there is no way to reach it from *PC2* through the *NAT*. Unless you configure port forwarding of the *NAT* or use some third-party *NAT* discovery services.

*NAT* port forwarding works in the following manner. If a port forward rule 
**(PC1 public ip address, port2) -- (PC1 internal ip address, port1)** is specified, all packets send to **(PC1 public ip address, port2)** are forwarded to **(PC1 internal ip address, port1)**.